# as2 getURL weird issue

Tags: actionscript-2, geturl

I have a weird issue with getURL.

I'm using the following command in an AS2 project and it's popping up a new window (without toolbars etc) instead of opening an entirely new tab in my browser. Is there a setting or something in cs 5.5 or is it something to do with the embed code? I've never seen this before!

```
getURL("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

There s no any new settings for as2 on cs5.5.